# Bootstrap Mobile Navigation Colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using latest bootstrap 3.2.0 and trying to get the mobile menu colors to display differently.

I'm having a really tough time updating a page I'm working on http://seattleasce.org/index_test.php. What I'm trying to do is change the color of the mobile version - the one that activates as `@media` query (sorry maybe that makes no sense).

I just don't know how to edit the CSS styles so that the page does not show grey text over the blue smaller navbar. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your CSS, making sure it loads AFTER Bootstrap

```
@media (max-width:767px){
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header{color:#fff}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a{color:#fff}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about it the wrong way, bootstrap3 was designed for mobiles first and then expanded out using media queries in contrast to designing for desktop first then trying to shrink with media queries.

For example look at the styling applied to the 'navbar-header' when in mobile mode:

http://puu.sh/bDyak.png

Now watch what happens as we expand out to a small device screen width:

http://puu.sh/bDyn2.PNG

Treat the mobile screen as the default

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks Matthew! With your theory and Fabio's code example I was able to correct it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad i could be of help